# A* Algorithm That Takes in a Graph

Tags: python, shortest-path, dijkstra, a-star

I am working on a project where I need a shortest path algorithm to, of course, find the shortest path. Currently I am using David Eppstein's implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm, but due to the large nature of the graph (about 3.6 million nodes), it can take almost a minute to find this shortest path. I know that the A* algorithm runs faster, but all implementations of I that I have found base it on a grid style versus a graph style. An example graph would look like this:

```
graph = {"A": {"B": 2}
     "B": {"A": 2, "C": 5, "D": 4}
     "C": {"B": 5, "E": 7}
     "D": {"B": 4, "E": 10}
     "E": {"C": 7, "D": 10}
    }
```

If anyone knows of some code online that implements A* to accept this kind of graph as input please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There's a python graph library called [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) 
that has all the common [shortest path](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.shortest_paths.html) algorithms implemented.